# How to convert string into float value in android

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String from EditText to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229710/string-from-edittext-to-float)

In application I want to convert the entered string in edit box to the corresponding value like `233243664376347845.89` to corresponding float value. But it returns like IE10 after some number for example `23324366IE10` Please help me. My code is -

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);

try 
{
    number = format.parse(e1.getText().toString());
} catch (ParseException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The edit text length is greater then 20 digits,also i want to minus two edit text float values...

Comment: use Float.valueOf(String) : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: The `double` value (it's not a `float`) is parsed just fine. The problem is that it's not *displayed* right. Where's the code that prints `number`?

Comment: Float f =Float.parseFloat(str);

Answer (score 55):

```
String s = e1.getText().toString();
Float f= Float.parseFloat(s);
```

Comment: You shall catch NumberFormatException in case of failures.

Answer (score 18):

This will solve your issue:

```
String str=e1.getText().toString();
number = Float.parseFloat(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_float);
float number = Float.valueOf(edt.getText().toString());
```

You use the valueOf() method if the Float wrapper class to convert a string to a float. IN this example I get the Editable object of that EditText with getText() on which I call the toString() method to obtain a string from it.

Comment: it working only 6 digits,we will enter greater than 6 digits means it shows 6857841E10

Comment: @user1235251 you get any solution for like this E10.