# Trying to multiply a TextField value by a double value

Tags: java, android, double

I am trying to get the value of inputEditText and multiply it by the value of convertNum.

The error I'm getting is: Operator '*' cannot be applied to 'android.widget.EditText','double'

I believe I need to convert the value of inputEditText into a number, but I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Declare variables
    final Button calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final TextView resultnumTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    final EditText inputEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final double convertNum = 0.125;

    // Set resultTextView to be invisible on app start
    resultTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    // When calculate button is pressed: Set resultTextView to visible and show result
    calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            resultTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            resultnumTextView.setText(inputEditText * convertNum);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I chose pelotasplus' answer because they explained why my code was wrong instead just correcting my code. Thank you for your answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error as you are trying to multiply EditText (which is a View instance) and double (which is a number).

Easiest fix is to replace

```
resultnumTextView.setText(inputEditText * convertNum);
```

with

```
resultnumTextView.setText(String.valueOf(
    Float.valueOf(inputEditText.getText().toString()) * convertNum
));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it. I'll need to familiarize myself with Float.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
resultnumTextView.setText(inputEditText * convertNum);
```

Do this:

```
resultnumTextView.setText(Double.parseDouble(inputEditText.getText().toString()) * convertNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

inputEditText is an EditText, a widget to write text. You need to extract the typed text and convert into a float.

```
inputEditText.getText().toString()
```

Will give you a String with the typed text. Then use the wrapper class Float to convert into a number

```
 String s = inputEditText.getText().toString();
 Float f= Float.parseFloat(s);
```

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735679/how-to-convert-string-into-float-value-in-android)

Answer (score -2):

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Declare variables
    final Button calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final TextView resultnumTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    final EditText inputEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final double convertNum = 0.125;

    // Set resultTextView to be invisible on app start
    resultTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    // When calculate button is pressed: Set resultTextView to visible and show result
    calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String valueFromInput = inputEditText.getText().toString();
            try{
               double valueToDouble = Double.parseDouble(valueFromInput);
               double result = convertNum * valueToDouble;
               resultnumTextView.setText(result+"");
               resultTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }catch(Exception e){
               // print the exception.
            }
        }
    });
}
```