# How to parse number string containing commas into an integer in java?

Tags: java, exception, number-formatting

I'm getting `NumberFormatException` when I try to parse 265,858 with `Integer.parseInt()`.

Is there any way to parse it into an integer?

Comment: the question is not clean, what is ','? thousands or decimal delimiter?

Comment: I think it is... Is there any way to parse it into **an** integer?

Comment: or is it 2 integers in a csv format? 265 and 858?

Comment: "an integer" is not 2 integers.

Comment: @OlivierRefalo The question is pretty clear for others(who answered) than for u.

Comment: @vivek_jonam, the original title was confusing before I edited it. In computer science, the term "comma separated" has a special meaning. When people read "comma separated", they expect to be dealing with a list of values separated by commas. Not a single value that uses commas for groupings.

Comment: FYI: depending on the region, the ',' and '.' can have different meanings. hence the int could be 265858 or just 265

Comment: @TimBender ok then my appologies.

Comment: Try String.split() at the comma or use the locale thing mentioned above

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Is this comma a decimal separator or are these two numbers? In the first case you must provide [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to [`NumberFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class that uses comma as decimal separator:

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRANCE).parse("265,858")
```

This results in `265.858`. But using US locale you'll get `265858`:

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(java.util.Locale.US).parse("265,858")
```

That's because in France they treat comma as decimal separator while in US - as grouping (thousand) separator.

If these are two numbers - `String.split()` them and parse two separate strings independently.

Comment: "parse it into an integer" pretty much narrows down the interpretation :)

Comment: Third option: it's a grouping separator.

Comment: Yes: one integer, thousands separator.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: thanks, I clarified it and added more examples. Indeed OP wants to parse **integers** - I missed that.

Comment: Is there no way to do this universally? After all, the user might have copied the number from somewhere that uses a different Locale than the one of the app.

Comment: unfortunatly, if we input "265-858" it will output "265" which is not desired. is there a way to make it more strict so it throws an exception?

Answer (score 22):

You can remove the `,` before parsing it to an int:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(myNumberString.replaceAll(",", ""));
```

Comment: Take note that `replaceAll` is used, critical for any number `>999,999`.  This also removes the need to throw/catch the checked exception from other answers.

Answer (score 13):

If it is one number & you want to remove separators, `NumberFormat` will return a number to you. Just make sure to use the correct Locale when using the `getNumberInstance` method.

For instance, some Locales swap the comma and decimal point to what you may be used to.

Then just use the `intValue` method to return an integer. You'll have to wrap the whole thing in a try/catch block though, to account for Parse Exceptions.

```
try {
    NumberFormat ukFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.UK);
    ukFormat.parse("265,858").intValue();
} catch(ParseException e) {
    //Handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to strip the commas:

```
"265,858".replaceAll(",","");
```

Comment: Simpler and faster solution: `replace` instead of `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing which clicks to me, assuming this is a single number, is...

```
String number = "265,858";
number.replaceAll(",","");
Integer num = Integer.parseInt(number);
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use `NumberFormat.parse`, setting it to be integer only.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String x = "265,858 ";
    x = x.split(",")[0];
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(x));
```

EDIT : 
if you want it rounded to the nearest Integer :

```
    String x = "265,858 ";
    x = x.replaceAll(",",".");
    System.out.println(Math.round(Double.parseDouble(x)));
```

Comment: That should give 265, he doesn't want it rounded or what so ever

Comment: But the number is `265858` or `265.858`

Comment: If you read OP question, you don't know if the number must be 265 or 265858. Even if it were 265, maybe OP needs it as 266.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with rounding, floating point or decimal numbers. Comma is quite simply a thousands separator and all the treatment it needs is **ignoring**.

Comment: Come on, well he just can use the replaceAll part, I've just shown something as an example, say some tweaks or whatever !