# How to change Stringtokenizer to String

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

I have my code here that would like to change Stringtokenizer to String because the information I get is in sentence and I would like to cut it down to certain part.

```
StringTokenizer numberOfPost_string = new StringTokenizer( numberOfPost_text , delimiters );

System.out.println( numberOfPost_string.nextToken() );

int numberOfPost = Integer.parseInt(numberOfPost_string);
```

The problem I encounter is on the `line int numberOfPost = Integer.parseInt(numberOfPost_string);` where it gives me error.

Or is there other way for me to cut down sentence and convert it to integer?

Comment: you need to post up the contents of numberOfPost_text and delimiters

Comment: What I get from numberOfPost_text is "1,221 ( 0.9 posts per day / 0.00% of total forum posts )". What I want is the 1,221 value from the string. My deliminators is the whitespace

Comment: use regular expressions for that, not string tokenizer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use the return value of `nextToken`:

```
StringTokenizer numberOfPost_string = new StringTokenizer( numberOfPost_text , delimiters );
int numberOfPost = Integer.parseInt(numberOfPost_string.nextToken());
```

You can also do it with [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29): (although this is probably slightly less efficient)

```
int numberOfPost = Integer.parseInt(numberOfPost_text.split(delimiters)[0]);
```

Keep in mind that `split` takes a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) `String`, thus to specify multiple options for characters, you will need to surround them by `[]`. To specify `;`, `,` or `:`:

```
String delimiters = "[;,:]";
```

Comment: There seems to be problem at `int numberOfPost = Integer.parseInt(numberOfPost_string.nextToken());`

I get errors on that line. Could you please help me check? Sorry, I'm new to Java.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,221"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at fyp.draft.pkg1.Design.jButton2ActionPerformed(Design.java:161) and many more

Comment: Which says exactly what it means. 1,221 is not a valid int. 1221 is.

Comment: @PohSun `1,221` cannot get parsed by `parseInt`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11973442/1711796).

Comment: @Dukeling. Got it. Sorry. Wasn't aware of it. My errors has been fixed. Sorry and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the tokens to string

```
String x = "";
StringTokenizer in = new StringTokenizer(str, ",;");
while(in.hasMoreTokens()) {
    x = x + in.nextToken().toString();
}
System.out.print(x);
```