# Sum of elements in "manual" Linked list java

Tags: java

I have a question about how to write a function that will give me the sum of elements in a manual linked list. I tried it like this but it doesn't work:
function insert() inserts elements in list.

```
public class list {
            int head;
            List tail;
            int sum=0;
            int value;
    public void insert(int elt){
        if(tail == null){

            tail = new list();
            tail.head = elt;

        }
        else{
        tail.insert(elt);
        }
    }
    public int sum(list head){
            if(head!=null){
                sum += head;
                return tail.sum(head);
            }
            return sum;
        }
}
```

Comment: Better to use English named variables, and `Seznam` is not a known type.

Comment: its the name of class: public class Seznam {

Comment: Doesn't tell us anything, we don't know what it is. See [MCVE] and [ask].

Comment: is this inner class "Seznam"?

Comment: yes it is @Lalit Verma

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the sum of a LinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102194/how-to-get-the-sum-of-an-linkedlist-sum-up-items-in-a-linkedlist).

Comment: it is not duplicate because i am not getting elements from database.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show all of the code that we would need to understand your code. You haven't given enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code for this kind of things (ie "manual" linked list iteration) is like this :

```
public int calculateSum(MyList list) {
    Node node = list.head();
    int sum = 0;
    while (node != null) {
        sum += node.value();
        node = node.next();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

With

```
class MyList {
    public Node head();
} 

class Node {
    public int value() ;
    public Node next() ;
}
```

Comment: Could you please write the whole function so i see which arguments are needed in the function

Comment: You will need to write the `MyList`  and `Node` classes yourself though.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use List Object from java ?
You can use this function for sum of elements in a list :

```
public static int sum (List<Integer> list) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i: list) {
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```