# sorting list of values in java after converting string to integer

Tags: java, sorting, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am doing some selenium automation test case and i am getting list of web element using the below code.

```
List<WebElement> list = GlobalVariables.BrowserDriver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Tbls_T']/tbody/tr/td[4]"));
```

and then i am iterating that web element and getting the values using

```
for (WebElement webElement : list) {

        System.out.println(webElement.getText());

}
```

so i am getting the values in string format. and sample values are giving below

-100,000
-80,000
0.100
2
87.270
3,000.000

I want to check these values in sorting order or not? for that i think i should convert to integer and then check using some kind of sorting method i guess. for that i have tried to convert the values to a list of integer and then use some sorting algorithm like Guava to check the sorting. because of negative values i am facing difficulty to do that.

Is there any way i can check the sorting order for the above problem and check the order of the values. ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Guava is not a sorting algorithm! Anyway, are you on *Java 8*?

Comment: Use Collection sort.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Nope. Not the answer the OP is expecting.

Comment: Are the values unique?

Comment: I am on java 7 . ok i saw that i can check the list is sorted or not using Guava. sorry if i am wrong.

Comment: no values are not unique.. it changes. its just sample which i have.

Comment: You can't convert these to `int` because you'll lose the decimal part in some of them. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973383/how-to-parse-number-string-containing-commas-into-an-integer-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse number string containing commas into an integer in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973383/how-to-parse-number-string-containing-commas-into-an-integer-in-java)

Comment: I don't see why you need to sort the values to check if they're sorted.  Can't you just compare each value with its previous and check the number is not smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to just check the incoming list is sorted or not.
You compare the previous value with current value. If previous value is greater than current value then the list is not sorted.

Sample code:

```
    WebElement prev=null;
    boolean isSorted = true;
    for (WebElement currentWebElement : list) {

        if (prev == null) {
            prev = currentWebElement;
            continue;
        } else {

            if (Double.compare(Double.parseDouble(prev.getText().replaceAll(",", "")),
                    Double.parseDouble(currentWebElement .getText().replaceAll(",", ""))) > 0) {
                isSorted = false;
                break;
            }

            prev = currentWebElement;

        }

    }
```

Comment: perfect.. this worked well.. thank you so much for the help Sumit.

Answer (score 0):

1. create 2 copies of your data
2. convert the first to integers and sort it
3. convert the second one to integers and leave it
4. check if the two lists are equal if they are then your list is sorted

Comment: i cannot convert to integer because of the negative values. getting exception. for example i am getting -100,000 and i tried this to convert this value Integer.parseInt(-100,000); but getting exception because of '-'

Comment: that's because their not integers
here is a solution : String s ="-100,000";
s = s.replaceAll(",","."); //to replace , with .
s = Double.parseDouble(s);
this should fix it

Answer (score 0):

Please use another list of doubles and Collections.sort(). You may have to remove the commas from strings

```
public class ConvertToIntSort 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) 
    {

       String[] strlist = {"-100000","0.100", "2" , "3000.000","87.270", "-80000" };
       java.util.List<String> stringlist =  Arrays.asList(strlist);
       java.util.List<Double> intList = new ArrayList<Double>();
       for(String str : stringlist)
       {          
         //converting and adding to double list  
         intList.add(Double.valueOf(str));

       }
        //Sorting is done here            
        Collections.sort(intList);

       for(Double num : intList)
       {
           System.out.println(num);         

       }

    }
}
```