# How to convert string with $ sing in it to int

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I have a string "$1,076.00" and I want to convert them in to int,
I capture some value $1,076.00 and saved in string called originalAmount, 
and tried int edited = Integer.parseInt(originalAmount); and it gave me error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$1,076.00"

can anyone help?

Comment: remove the undesired part, then parse the string to double

Comment: you have a non numeric expression.

you should remove the $ from the expression and since you manipulate double values you should parse the string as a Double.

Comment: what if the amount is `$1,122.33` then what should be the output because `int` won't be able to store `.33`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I  only sening int value to input and it gives $by default so when I get value and save in string It will always give .00 back

Comment: try this  `int d= Integer.valueOf("$1,076.00".replaceAll("\\.0+|[^\\d]+", ""));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse number string containing commas into an integer in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973383/how-to-parse-number-string-containing-commas-into-an-integer-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone yr answers help me a lot
I have come up with

originalAmount = originalAmount.substring(1);

```
    if (originalAmount.contains("$")) {
        originalAmount = originalAmount.replace("$", "");
    }

    newOriginalAmt = Double.parseDouble(originalAmount);
    System.out.println(newOriginalAmt);
```

pls let me know yr thoughts

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the undesired part ($ sign) and then parse the string to double carefully since the decimal part is a locale dependent

```
String pay = "$1,076.00";
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
Number number = format.parse(pay.replace("$", ""));
double result = number.doubleValue();
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String originalAmount="$1076.00";
String amount = originalAmount.replace($,"");
int edited = Integer.parseInt(amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string sourceString = "$1,076.00";
sourceString.substring(1, sourceString.length() - 1)
int foo = Integer.parseInt(sourceString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String amount = "$1,076,.00";
 String formatted = amount.replace("$", ""); // remove "$" sign
 formatted = formatted.replace(",", ""); // remove "," signs from number

 double amountDouble = Double.parseDouble(formatted); // convert to double
 int amountInt = (int)amountDouble; // convert double value to int
 System.out.println(amountInt); // prints out 1076
```