# Selenium WD | Exception error appears after using parsing of String into double

Tags: string, parsing, selenium-webdriver, double, gettext

Parsing is not working for me -
After getting 'newSocket' as a String with getText(), I'm trying to parse it into a double , and I get an exception error after running the test. Please help

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SeleniumPractice2investing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\automation\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.investing.com"); 



        driver.navigate().refresh();
        WebElement e1 = driver.findElement(By.id("searchTextTop")); 
        e1.sendKeys("BTC/USD");
        Thread.sleep(5000); // Wait until it is loaded
        WebElement e2 = driver.findElement(By.id("symbol_BTC/USD"));
        e2.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        WebElement e3 = driver.findElement(By.id("last_last"));
        String newSocket = e3.getText();
        Thread.sleep(1);


        double CurrentSocketValue = Double.valueOf(newSocket); // Getting Exception error here
```

Comment: when adding a "test" command as such:

System.out.println("Test" +newSocket);
double CurrentSocketValue = Double.valueOf(newSocket);

>I get a numeric value (As a string, so it is not an empty String)

Comment: I Think I've Got it !

As the number comes in a String with punctuation (I.e. 2,4544.5)
Should I remove punctuation before using parsing, as such :  String123 = newSocket.replaceAll("[\\W]", "");

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the Exception message?

From what you have posted i can only guess that the `e3.getText()` is an empty string. 
You could check for an empty string and set `newSocket` a default value.

If it is a string then there are other methods you can use in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973383/how-to-parse-number-string-containing-commas-into-an-integer-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

Empty String it is.  The reason is that the number is received as so "2,749.79" with punctuations,  I found a solution to ignore punctuations and it solved it (added a comment above)