# Java Convert String into BigDecimal

Tags: java, string, type-conversion, format, bigdecimal

I have to convert a `String` (read from excel cell) into `BigDecimal`, but I have to consider :

- the `BigDecimal` number will have two decimal digits, so I must form it in that way
- the original string could use comma (",") as decimal separator (and this is my greater problem because if I write `BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(rowCell);` and rowCell has comma as decimal separator I will take an exception...)

Could you help me?
Thank you in advance

Comment: `"the original string could use comma"`: **could** or **will**?

Comment: "Could". Because some users will use dot but I must be able to predict the use of the comma. Thank yuo for the help

Comment: This answer will help you in this situation:
[How to parse number string containing commas into an integer in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973383/how-to-parse-number-string-containing-commas-into-an-integer-in-java)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to be usefull in case of integer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it by steps:

- replace the comma `,` by a dot `.`
- get a `BigDecimal` from this new string
- round it to 2 decimals with `ROUND_DOWN` or `ROUND_UP`

---

```
String str = "123,456";                   // String 132,456
str = str.replace(',', '.');              // String 132.456
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(str);       // BigDec 132.456
b = b.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN); // BigDec 132.45
```

If you concat you have :

```
String str = "123,456";                  
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(str.replace(',', '.')).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
```

---

[***Working DEMO***](https://ideone.com/73IJ2Y)

Comment: @Lorenzo *elegant* ? You can print flowers around if you want^^

Answer (score 0):

Just replace a comma with a dot. It's simple and fast enough.

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(rowCell.replace(',', '.'));
```